# Initializing firebase phone auth within expo react-native application

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase phone auth in my react native application, I have copied the code from the expo documentation as it is, at the first time it worked with recaptcha feature and otp message sending. but when I tried a second time it shows me the error :

> [Error: Either an instance of firebase.auth.Auth must be passed as an argument to the firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider constructor, or the default firebase App instance must be initialized via firebase.initializeApp().]

My firebase app is already initialized and there is no passing arguments to the specified method in the error from the expo documentation.
So I cannot really follow the origin of the error.

Here is the code that I have used from the documentation:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
} from "react-native";
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from "expo-firebase-recaptcha";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import firebaseConfig from "../Config/firebaseConfig";

// Initialize Firebase JS SDK
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
try {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    firebaseConfig,
  });
} catch (err) {
  // ignore app already initialized error in snacé
}

export default function App() {
  const recaptchaVerifier = React.useRef(null);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = React.useState();
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = React.useState();
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = React.useState();
  const firebaseConfig = firebase.apps.length
    ? firebase.app().options
    : undefined;

  const [message, showMessage] = React.useState(
    !firebaseConfig || Platform.OS === "web"
      ? {
          text:
            "To get started, provide a valid firebase config in App.js and open this snack on an iOS or Android device.",
        }
      : undefined
  );

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 20, marginTop: 50 }}>
      <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
        ref={recaptchaVerifier}
        firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
      />
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter phone number</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ marginVertical: 10, fontSize: 17 }}
        placeholder="+1 999 999 9999"
        autoFocus
        autoCompleteType="tel"
        keyboardType="phone-pad"
        textContentType="telephoneNumber"
        onChangeText={(phoneNumber) => setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Send Verification Code"
        disabled={!phoneNumber}
        onPress={async () => {
          // The FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal ref implements the
          // FirebaseAuthApplicationVerifier interface and can be
          // passed directly to `verifyPhoneNumber`.
          try {
            const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber,
              recaptchaVerifier.current
            );
            setVerificationId(verificationId);
            showMessage({
              text: "Verification code has been sent to your phone.",
            });
          } catch (err) {
            showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: "red" });
          }
        }}
      />
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter Verification code</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ marginVertical: 10, fontSize: 17 }}
        editable={!!verificationId}
        placeholder="123456"
        onChangeText={setVerificationCode}
      />
      <Button
        title="Confirm Verification Code"
        disabled={!verificationId}
        onPress={async () => {
          try {
            const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId,
              verificationCode
            );
            await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
            showMessage({ text: "Phone authentication successful " });
          } catch (err) {
            showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: "red" });
          }
        }}
      />
      {message ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
            { backgroundColor: 0xffffffee, justifyContent: "center" },
          ]}
          onPress={() => showMessage(undefined)}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              color: message.color || "blue",
              fontSize: 17,
              textAlign: "center",
              margin: 20,
            }}
          >
            {message.text}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : undefined}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Any help with this error please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out, the problem was with my config file :
old version:

```
export default firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
};
```

Solution version:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "@firebase/auth";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
};
try {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} catch (e) {}
export default firebase;
```

I was doing the initialize firebase in the component class but that led me to another error.
So the perfect solution to my problem is this one.

Comment: Do you remember what you put in for Hostname field in the Firebase Auth console? I keep getting denied response because of unknown hostname, I am not sure what to put there as I am running this in Expo and not on the web.